# Open new window on click of instagram embed in facebook instant article

Tags: instagram, facebook-instant-articles

I have instagram embed in facebook instant article. But on clicking the instagram image I get sign in page right inside the embed. I want it to be opened outside facebook in a new window. Can someone please let me know how to do that?
Here is my code:

```
<figure class="op-interactive">
  <iframe>
    <blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned>
        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/p/shortcode/embed/captioned/" target="_blank"></a>
    </blockquote>
    <script src="https://platform.instagram.com/en_US/embeds.js"></script>
  </iframe>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code work for me.

```
<figure class="op-interactive"><iframe><blockquote class="instagram-media" data-instgrm-captioned data-instgrm-permalink="Url"></blockquote><script async src="//www.instagram.com/embed.js"></script></iframe></figure>
```